# Qt: Simple Example for Quazip

Tags: qt, quazip

I built the quazip library. I need a simple example that shows how to unzip a zip File. For example.

```
Quazip zipFile( QFile("test.zip") );
zipFile.unzip();
```

Tests shown in quazip is little bit confusing. I searched for a brief amount of time to find an example and I wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a quick example showing how to read the files.  You will need to make some modifications to the code in the loop to write the data to a file or perform whatever operations your application requires:

```
QuaZip zip("zipFile.zip");
zip.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip);

QuaZipFile file(&zip);

for(bool f=zip.goToFirstFile(); f; f=zip.goToNextFile()) {
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    //same functionality as QIODevice::readData() -- data is a char*, maxSize is qint64
    file.readData(data,maxSize);
    //do something with the data
    file.close();
}

zip.close();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use static functions of the class JlCompress. It's very easy to use.

**Static Public Member Functions**

```
static bool     compressFile (QString fileCompressed, QString file)
static bool     compressFiles (QString fileCompressed, QStringList files)
static bool     compressDir (QString fileCompressed, QString dir=QString(), bool recursive=true)
static QString  extractFile (QString fileCompressed, QString fileName, QString fileDest=QString())
static QStringList  extractFiles (QString fileCompressed, QStringList files, QString dir=QString())
static QStringList  extractDir (QString fileCompressed, QString dir=QString()) 
static QStringList  getFileList (QString fileCompressed)
```

Source: http://quazip.sourceforge.net/classJlCompress.html